# different email intents from buttons on dialog

Tags: android, email, android-intent, dialog

I have only one screen with a button ( I will add more later). But for now, I want to make it so that when the button is clicked, it will pop up a dialog box with two options. Both options will be email intents it is only the data passed to the email client that is different. Is this possible? I am a new developer, and this is one of my starter projects, so please bear with me. Thanks in advance.

Okay, so I found my answer (I put this in the onClick() method):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogActivity.this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Save File...");

            // Setting Dialog Message
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to save this file?");

            // Setting Icon to Dialog
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.save);

            // Person presses first option (first email)
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
               Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "email@domain.com" });
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
                }
            });

            // Person presses second option (second email)
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "example@domain.com" });
                    emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
                }
            });

            // Put a "cancel" button
            alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Cancel",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            // Show the dialog
            alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one intent and use **PutExtra()** for Intents and depends on the button click you can add the data to the Extra that can be used in the Email client.

Answer (score 1):

```
CharSequence[] arrayMail = {"first mail option", "second one"};
            builder.setTitle("Mail").setItems(arrayMail, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(which==0)
                    {
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "first data" });
                        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email ..."));
                    }
                    if(which==1)
                    {
                        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[] { "Second data" });
                        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Send email"));
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialogSeguin = builder.create();
            dialogSeguin.show();
```

Of course it's better to use "strings.xml" for characters chains

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming... Why does it give me an error on the word "builder"? It says "builder cannot be resolved". I tried to make it into the builder for AlertDialogs but it gives me more errors. I've put your code into the onClick() method of the button. Thanks a ton